# XElement parsing from XDocument, far below, repeated 3

Tags: c#, xml, foreach

```
//      <sdl:seg id="1" conf="Translated">
//              <sdl:previous origin="source">
//                      <sdl:value key="created">Quick</sdl:value>
//                      <sdl:value key="modified">Brown</sdl:value></sdl:previous>
//              <sdl:value key="created">Fox</sdl:value>
//              <sdl:value key="modified">Jumps</sdl:value></sdl:seg>             

foreach (XElement x in myDoc.Descendants(ns + "seg"))           
    foreach (XElement y in myDoc.Descendants(ns + "value"))
        foreach (var z in y.Attributes())
            if (z.Value == "modified")      
                MessageBox.Show(y.Value);
```

I had "Brown" and "Jumps".

I want to have only "Jumps". (I mean only children not grandchild"s")

Help please.

At the moment, I'm studying only for "foreach" loops not LINQ (I know that is good one).

Regards.

**[Edit]** How about this. It emits nothing..

```
foreach (var x in d.Descendants("seg").Elements("value").Attributes().Some("modified")
    MessageBox.Show(x.Value);
```

[Edit 2]

```
foreach (var x in d.Descendants("seg").Elements("value").Attributes().Where(x => x.Value == "modified"))
MessageBox.Show( x.Parent.Value);
```

[Edit 3]

```
foreach (var x in d.Descendants("seg").Elements("value").Where(x => x.Attribute("key").Value == "modified"))
MessageBox.Show(x.Value);
```

Comment: This way you get the attributes, but not elements.

Comment: Yap... I found it. Though it is mixed with LINQ, mainly it is foreach...

Comment: Ahh. Thanks comment again.

Comment: Yeah, it's a linq way. But a little bit ugly, huh?

Comment: I have changed little bit.... Yes. I agreed with you. Not so beautiful.

Comment: Thanks. Alexander Petrov. Your comments were great helps to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Elements` instead of `Descendants`.

```
foreach (XElement x in myDoc.Descendants(ns + "seg").Elements(ns + "value"))           
    foreach (var z in x.Attributes())
        if (z.Value == "modified")      
            MessageBox.Show(x.Value);
```

---

A shorter version:

```
foreach (XElement x in myDoc.Descendants(ns + "seg").Elements(ns + "value"))
    if (x.Attributes().Any(a => a.Value == "modified"))
        MessageBox.Show(x.Value);
```

Comment: Oh my, that is too easy.

Comment: Thanks. I am an ediot.